# How can I feed a numpy array to a prefetch and buffer pipeline of TensorFlow

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

I tried to follow the [Cifar10 example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_input.py#L138). However, I want to replace the file reading with the Numpy array. There are a few benefits for doing that:

- Simpler code (I want to remove the binary file parsing)
- Simpler graph and visualization --> easier to explain to other audience
- Small perf improvement (due to I/O and parsing)?

What would be a simple way to do it?

Comment: To be clear, you want to remove the part with the preprocessing queue and replace the input data with numpy arrays containing cifar images?

Comment: I want to keep the preprocessing part, e.g. image distortion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the tensor `reshape_image` by either:

- giving it a name
- finding its default name, with Tensorboard for instance

---

```
reshaped_image = tf.cast(read_input.uint8image, tf.float32, name="float_image")
```

---

Then you can feed your numpy array using a feed_dict like:

```
reshaped_image = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("float_image")
sess.run(loss, feed_dict={reshaped_image: your_numpy})
```

The same goes for labels.